# AWS - Load balancer with TLS termination but using self-signed certs to back-ends?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, load-balancing, tls1.2, amazon-elb

**Question**

Is it possible to have a load balancer in AWS handle TLS termination for a real certificate, while also having it use a self-signed certificate on the back-end?  If so, how?

---

**Conext**

This way, I could pay for the certificate once for one server (the LB) and then still have TLS between the LB and the large number of back-end servers.  The front-end user would be happy as they would get a real cert and no warnings, and the back-end app would be secure via the self-signed cert.

Answer (score 1):

Thats possible, You can use trusted cert on ELB and self signed cert on backend. once you configure listener (for frontend on port 443 and valid cert) and Target group on port 443 for backend, the entire traffic should be encrypted. Client would see cert used on ELB/ALB and you can also restrict backend to allow connects only from ELB/ALB.

You can use ACM cert on ELB/ALB which is free.

Comment: Will this solution work with Traefik terminatinfg LetsEncrypt certificates at the back end proxy server and ALB terminating SSL with an ACM certificate? Does the ALB then forward SSL to the back end or tcp port 80? The Traefik proxy has a redirect to https if it gets traffic on port 80. I would like the final certificate at the browser to be verified by Amazon.